# Pyspark convert df to array of objects

Tags: pyspark

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

simpleData = [("James", "Sales", "NY", 90000, 34, 10000),
                ("Michael", "Sales", "NY", 86000, 56, 20000),
                ("Robert", "Sales", "CA", 81000, 30, 23000),
                ("Maria", "Finance", "CA", 90000, 24, 23000),
                ("Raman", "Finance", "CA", 99000, 40, 24000),
                ("Scott", "Finance", "NY", 83000, 36, 19000),
                ("Jen", "Finance", "NY", 79000, 53, 15000),
                ("Jeff", "Marketing", "CA", 80000, 25, 18000),
                ("Kumar", "Marketing", "NY", 91000, 50, 21000)
                ]
schema = ["employee_name", "department",
            "state", "salary", "age", "bonus"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=simpleData, schema=schema)
data = df.groupBy("department").count() \
    .select(col("department").alias("name"), col("count").alias("value")) \
    .toJSON().collect()
print(data)

spark.stop()
```

When I ran the code it gives an array string:

```
[
 '{"name":"Sales","value":3}', 
 '{"name":"Finance","value":4}', 
 '{"name":"Marketing","value":2}'
]
```

but I don't want an array string, I want an array object to send to frontend

```
[
 {"name":"Sales","value":3}, 
 {"name":"Finance","value":4}, 
 {"name":"Marketing","value":2}
]
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What happens if you call `.collect` before calling `.toJSON` ?

Comment: It throws an exception
`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'toJSON'`

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `toJSON()` and use the following list comprehension

```
[d.asDict() for d in data]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to deserialize the json on the driver side:

```
import json
deserialized_data = [json.loads(s) for s in data]

print(deserialized_data)
print(deserialized_data[0]["name"])
```

If you add the above lines after the collect, then `deserialized_data` will be a list of dictionary objects.

Output of the two prints with your provided data:

```
[{'name': 'Finance', 'value': 4}, {'name': 'Sales', 'value': 3}, {'name': 'Marketing', 'value': 2}]
Finance
```